# Why does pylint label this an undefined variable but the code still works?

Tags: python, pylint

I just inherited some code and don't understand what pylint is complaining about here.

[image]

Why does pylint detect this variable `protocol` as `undefined-variable`? The code still runs. I've tried the following in a python shell as well

```
Python 3.9.13 (main, Aug 11 2022, 14:05:15) 
[Clang 13.1.6 (clang-1316.0.21.2.5)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> test_config = {
...   "protocol1": {
...     "files": ["file1"]
...   },
...   "protocol2": {
...     "files": [
...       "file2"
...     ]
...   }
... }
>>> [(p, f) for p in test_config for f in test_config[p]["files"]]
[('protocol1', 'file1'), ('protocol2', 'file2')]
```

Comment: I got `Consider iterating with .items() (14:0) [consider-using-dict-items]` on my machine. Maybe you should use `[(p, f) for p, files in test_config.items() for f in files["files"]]`? This is a more pythonic approach.

Comment: The code in the image is entirely different from the code you entered in Python shell. The latter looks good, but the `protocol` name in the `for` clause in the former code indeed looks undefined as marked by pylint. Unless you have it defined elsewhere through some dynamically injected means, I don't see how the former code can run without errors.